# object has no attribute get while overriding the POST method

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

```
class CreatePosts(CreateView):
    model = posts
    fields = ['title','comments']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        current_inspectionfile = Inspectionfile.objects.get(pk =   self.kwargs['pk'])
        new_post =   posts.objects.create(inspectionfile=current_inspectionfile,
                 title =request.POST.get("title"),
                 comments =request.POST.get("comments"))

       return new_post
```

Models

```
class posts(models.Model):
    inspectionfile = models.ForeignKey(Inspectionfile,   on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    comments = models.TextField()
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('posts_form', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form is a simple template:

```
<form class = "form_horizontal" action = "" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


my url is:
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.CreatePosts.as_view(),name=='posts_form')
```

The error I am getting is

> "posts" object has no attribute get.

I have tried seeing other blogs but nothing seems to work. I have overridden the post method in CreatePosts class to work in a certain way. Is this why I am getting this error or is it because of some URL mismatch. Once the user hits submit I want them to come back to the same form hence the URL.

Comment: Why are you overriding `post` at all? You should do this logic in `form_valid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post method is returning an instance of your model

```
return new_post
```

All views must return a HttpResponse so the simplest thing to return with your new post in the context would be `render`

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'new_post': new_post })
```